# Map query parameters to the model with custom converter

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following request to my **REST API**:

```
GET {hostname}:{port}/entity?code=123&recordId=422&prop1=123&prop2=213&propN=512
```

I want to convert query parameters to model:

```
public class EntityFilter { 
  private String code;
  private String recordId;
  private MultiValueMap<String, String> props; //all props goes here eg prop1=123, prop2=213

  //getters and setters are ommited
}
```

And get this model as an input parameter to the controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/entities", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity getEntities(EntityFilter filter) {
   //code
}
```

Using set up like this, I will have "**code**" and "**recordId**" populated with proper values but "**props**" map would be empty.

***How can I tell Spring to populate model object according to some custom converter or something?***

I have tried to use:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(EntityFilter.class, new FilterProperyEditor());
}
```

But actual methods of **FilterPropertyEditor** like **setAsText(String text)** are not being executed at all.

Comment: You didn't send a value for 'prop'. You could try and pass an object to it thou

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to change the query to

```
GET {hostname}:{port}/entity?code=123&recordId=422&props[0]=123&props[1]=213&props[N]=512
```

Comment: There can be another query parameter eg. name=jhon and I want it also go to the **props** list in the model class. In other words, all query params besides **code** and **recordId** should go to this list.